# Resolving dining philosophers deadlock using semaphores

Tags: c, operating-system, posix, semaphore

I am trying to solve the dining philosophers problem using semaphores in C. Below is my code. In the code each chopstick is represented by a semaphore. Each philosopher is a process. I use the concept that atmost 4 chopsticks can be in "picked up" state at any given time to avoid deadlock. That is why I set dt to 4. Please let me if the below code is correct and the if the logic is sound

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define STACKSIZE 10000
#define NUMPROCS 5
#define ROUNDS 10

sem_t dt,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;

int child (void * philNum) {
    int* phil1 = (int *)philNum;
    int phil = *phil1;
    int i = 0 ;

    for ( ; i < ROUNDS ; i ++ ) {
        switch(phil){

            case 1:
                sem_wait(&dt);
                sem_wait(&c1);
                sem_wait(&c5);
            case 2:
                sem_wait(&dt);
                sem_wait(&c1);
                sem_wait(&c2);
            case 3:
                sem_wait(&dt);
                sem_wait(&c3);
                sem_wait(&c2);
            case 4:
                sem_wait(&dt);
                sem_wait(&c4);
                sem_wait(&c3);
            case 5:
                sem_wait(&dt);
                sem_wait(&c4);
                sem_wait(&c5);
            default:
                perror(NULL);
                exit(1);
        }

        // Start of critical section -- 
        int sleeptime = rand()%20000 ;
        if ( sleeptime > 10000 ) usleep(sleeptime) ;

        // exit protocol here
        switch(phil){

            case 1:
                sem_post(&dt);
                sem_post(&c1);
                sem_post(&c5);
            case 2:
                sem_post(&dt);
                sem_post(&c1);
                sem_post(&c2);
            case 3:
                sem_post(&dt);
                sem_post(&c3);
                sem_post(&c2);
            case 4:
                sem_post(&dt);
                sem_post(&c4);
                sem_post(&c3);
            case 5:
                sem_post(&dt);
                sem_post(&c4);
                sem_post(&c5);
            default:
                perror(NULL);
                exit(1);
        }

    }
    return 0 ;
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    int i, num ;
    int *pt= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    void * p ;
    srand(time(NULL));
    sem_init(&c1,1,1);
    sem_init(&c2,1,1);
    sem_init(&c3,1,1);
    sem_init(&c4,1,1);
    sem_init(&c5,1,1);
    sem_init(&dt,1,4); //only 4 chopsticks can be picked up at a time. 5th one has to wait anyways as he cant eat with one chopstick
    for ( i = 0 ; i < NUMPROCS ; i ++ ) {
        p = malloc(STACKSIZE) ;
        if ( p == NULL ) {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n") ;
            exit(1) ;
        }
        *pt = i+1;

        int c = clone(child,p+STACKSIZE-1,CLONE_VM|SIGCHLD,(void *)pt,NULL) ;
        if ( c < 0 ) {
            perror(NULL) ;
            exit(1) ;
        }
    }
    for ( ; i > 0 ; i -- ) wait(NULL) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. interesting that we're doing this exact same problem in my Operating Systems and Concurrent Programming class... this in Cleveland by any chance?

Comment: This is a common problem and one of the main examples in many CS courses.

Comment: this is not in cleveland

Comment: @billy anyways, if the solution is the same, this a case of plagiarism as this is my original solution :)

Answer (score 6):

Your cases are falling through.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem here (but it's not really related to the parallelism of the problem you're working on):

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

is before your `clone` call. Basically, each clone of your process is going to have the same random seed. Thus any calls to `rand`, assuming they occur in the same order, are going to result in the same resultant "random" number.

What you should probably do instead is make the random seed dependent on the process ID, and do the initialization after you have cloned out the various processes. That way you'll get the random behavior you're expecting.

As for correctness of the overall algorithm ... have you tried running it?

Comment: I tried running it. It compiles without errors but then just hangs

Comment: How do you know if it hangs or not? There doesn't seem to be anything going on here but having everyone run forever...

Comment: @Billy. No, the loop runs only 10 times. Please see the child() function

Comment: for ( ; i < ROUNDS ; i ++ ) {

Comment: @Programmer: You asked with the logic was sound. I found one case where the logic was not sound and pointed it out. I don't see how that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @Programmer: Please stop asking for upvotes and shouting at people trying to help you. People upvote whenever they like your question, not because you ask for it. Besides, it's pretty rude to SHOUT to the only one who's taken the effort to help you.